# How to create a hybrid_property that incorporates split()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the simple table:

```
class Result(Base):
    __tablename__ = "result"

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    result = Column(String(20))
```

Where `result` records are of the form `6-1`, `7-5` etc.

I'd like to create a property that sums the integers in the `result` field, e.g. `6-1` would be `7`. I've tried the following:

```
@hybrid_property
def sum_games(self):
    return sum(int(s) for s in self.result.split("-"))
```

But I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Result.result has an attribute 'split'
```

I understand enough of Python to get that `self.result` isn't a string so I can't use the `split()` method. Is there a way to convert this to a string? I've tried `str(self.result)` but that returns `Result.result`.

Maybe there's another way to achieve the output I'm looking for?

Worth me mentioning that the `result` strings are actually a little more complicated than the examples above but I always need the `split()` method so I've simplified for this post.

Answer (score 2):

Hybrid properties have two parts, a Python part and a SQL part, which is denoted with the decorator `@sum_games.expression`. If you don't specify that `expression` counterpart, the hybrid property itself is used in SQL as well. But `.split()` and all the other python functions are unknown there, so try the following instead:

```py
@hybrid_property
def sum_games(self):
    return sum(int(s) for s in self.result.split("-"))

@sum_games.expression
def sum_games(cls):  # yes this is a class method for some reason
    sum_part_array = func.regexp_split_to_array(cls.result, '-')
    sum_parts = func.unnest(sum_part_array).alias("y")
    sum_clause = func.sum(cast(column("y"), Integer)

    return select([sum_clause]).select_from(sum_parts).as_scalar()
```

With translates to the SQL:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(y::int) FROM unnest(regexp_split_to_array(x, '-')) as y)
FROM (values ('6-1'), ('7-1')) as bla(x)
```

This works with PostgreSQL, if you use a different dialect, the same logic should hold with the equivalent functions

Comment: Thanks a million for this. Annoyingly MySQL doesn't appear to have anything like `regexp_split_to_array`. Currently investigating what options there are in `func`...

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem to have that, but if you [define your own function](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) you can also access it through `func`